# in R: Combining rows that are almost duplicates into one row with differing element combined

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I've got this `data.frame` that has the form like:

```
my_df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 3), 
                 title = c("YourMa", "YourMa", "MyMa", "HisMa"), 
                autqty = c(2, 2, 1, 1), 
                   aut = c("Steve", "Joe", "Albert", "Kevin"), 
                  pubb = c("Good", "Good", "Meh", "Fan"))
```

which looks like:

```
> my_df
id  title   autqty aut    pubb
1   YourMa     2   Steve  Good
1   YourMa     2   Joe    Good
2   MyMa       1   Albert Meh
3   HisMa      1   Kevin  Fan
```

Note that for `id` `1`, all of the info is the same except for the one `aut` entry.  **My goal** is to slim-down `my_df` such that the `aut` data is combined into one element:

```
  id  title  autqty  aut         pubb
   1 YourMa    2     Steve, Joe  Good
   2 MyMa      1     Albert      Meh
   3 HisMa     1     Kevin       Fan
```

Note: this is a smaller version of my original data.  I'd like to be able to handle any number of `aut`'s that occur.

Comment: your example says the first two rows' ids are 1 and 2, but your insert has them as 1 and 1 -- I just want to clarify that I assume you mean they should be 1 and 1 for YourMa

Comment: thanks - I've updated so that it's now correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `group_by` and `summarise` in `dplyr`:

```
my_df %>% 
  group_by(id, title, autqty, pubb) %>%
  summarise(aut=paste(aut, collapse=", ")) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 × 5
     id  title autqty   pubb        aut
  <dbl> <fctr>  <dbl> <fctr>      <chr>
1     1 YourMa      2   Good Steve, Joe
2     2   MyMa      1    Meh     Albert
3     3  HisMa      1    Fan      Kevin
```